# Get originating port from ActionExecutingContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging

Is it possible to get the originating port from an ActionExecutingContext object? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, look at `ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Port;`

Answer (score 4):

use this:
context.HttpContext.Request.Path
OR
context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase

Comment: Im using ASP.NET CORE MVC which didnt have Url, but did have this Path, for me this was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

ActionExecutionContext.HttpContextBase.Url.Port should work for you.